# Insert html dynamically with JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

My website structure is like this:

**menu.jsp**

```
...
`<li id="menu"><a href="index.jsp?page=pizzas"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>Pizzas</a></li>`
...
```

**index.jsp**

```
...
<c:when test="${param.page == 'pizzas'}">
     <jsp:include page="/pages/cadastro/pizzas.jsp" />
</c:when>
...
```

**pizzas.jsp**

```
<c:forEach var="pizza" items="${pizzas}">
    <td data-title="#">${pizza.id}</td>
    <td data-title="Description">${pizza.description}</td>
    <td data-title="Type">${pizza.type}</td>
</c:forEach>
```

My problem happens when trying to insert html on **pizzas.jsp**: how can I use a servlet to populate my `<td>`'s? Where should it be called? I've thought on calling an `ajax` function when `pizzas.jsp` is ready like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $.ajax({
        url: "PizzaController?action=listPizzas",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) { 

        },
        complete: function() {
            alert('complete');
        }
    });
}
```

and in my Servlet (`PizzaController`):

```
private void listPizzas(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<Pizza> pizzas = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        pizzas = pizzaDaoImpl.findAll();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    request.setAttribute("pizzas", pizzas);

    try {
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp?page=pizzas");
        rd.forward(request,response);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServletException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The problem doing this way is that **pizzas.jsp** would be called twice: 1) on menu click; 2) on ajax call.

So, what's the best way to insert dynamyc html in this scenario?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Are you trying to avoid reloading the page to update the table that is displayed in pizzas.jsp? To update the table dynamically based on a button click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saying that you have a controller, but you're not respecting the principle of MVC. The principle of MVC is the following one: requests are sent to controllers; controllers prepare a model and dispatch to a view; the view generates HTML code by getting data out of the model.

So, you should never have a link pointing to index.jsp, because index.jsp is a view. All your links should point to a controller:

```
<a href="pizzas">...</a>
```

A servlet (the controller) should then be mapped to the path `pizzas`. This servlet will do what your `listPizzas()` method already doesn except it should dispatch to an appropriate view (not to the same index.jsp page again and again):

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pizzas.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Using a single index.jsp page for the whole application is not a good idea. The page will quickly become huge and unmaintainable. You should have a separate JSP for each view. You can use a template engine (sitemesh, tiles, etc.) or simply includes to avoid duplicating the common elements (the menu, footer, etc.) on every view.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that... I knew there was something wrong in my MVC structure. I'm gonna refactor the code the way you said.